# how to render HTML entities to normal character into ASP literal control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

how there,
I've these codes in my DATABASE in other words it's HTML. I tried these stuff:

```
<div runat="server" id="div1" visible="false"> 
    <asp:Literal ID="literal1" runat="server" Text="" />
</div>
```

I tried in C# code behind:

```
div1.InnerText = contents; 
div1.InnerHtml = contents
literal1.Text  = contents;
```

But is still doesn't render well. I displays the original values in stead of a table and cells and columns. colours etc. etc....

What am I missing?

All these HTML's are in DABASE.Column e.g. column "Contents"
e.g.

```
"& lt;p class=& quot;MsoNormal&quot; style= &quot;color: #339966;&quot;&gt;&lt"

;&quot ;&gt ;&lt ;strong &gt ;&l

ot; &gt ;&amp ;nbsp; &lt ;/span &gt;&lt ;/p &gt;
```

Can someone please advice? what I'm I misssing?

I've put (spaces between & and gt above code otherwise it was not showing in stackoverflow.) The HTML sysntaxs are correct because it's created by an HTMLEDITOR.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
literal1.Text  = this.HtmlDecode(contents);
```

Comment: Just correction: in database it's correect ( lik <P> or <span> but it enders &gt.... I tried <litAbstract2.InnerText = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(agendaItem.detail);  I also tried htmlDecode

Answer (score 1):

Try `response.Write(Contents)`

And take a look at [HtmlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx)

Are you saying that `;&gt ;&lt` etc is displaying on the browser, or only when you view the source?

Comment: SORRY... A CORRECTION...HTMLEditor is generating this p style="COLOR: rgb(51,153,102)" class="MsoNormal"><strong><span style="FONT-SIZE: 36pt">    SO WITHOUT & code etc..... but on the screen it displays with &  (ampersand)   &lt;p class=&quot;MsoNormal&quot; style=&quot;color: #339966;&quot;&gt;

Comment: litAbstract2.InnerText = Response.Write(agendaItem.detail);  is generating syntax error... Resonse.write doesn't return value (void).

Comment: Sorry - You want Response.Write() to be by itself

Comment: What do you mean by it self ?.. I've HTML like (<p><span><table></span> in dabatabase column stored (rendered by a HTMLEDditor). I just want in another view display the results.  I can change the literal to another control if it's needed but HTML is rendered with &... sorry for the confusing.